# Does the Soul Society know exactly where Kisuke Urahara is?

Tags: bleach

I was under the impression that Kisuke's shop is where it is in order to stay out of the eyes of the Soul Society. Yet during the start of Season 4, Renji is "mooching" off the Urahara Shop, and it doesn't seem like Renji was in need to help at any time which would lead to Kisuke offering help, unlike with Rukia where it was shown that after she lost her powers she was approached by Kisuke.

So I am wondering if the Soul Society knew that Kisuke was set up in Karakura Town and thus directed Renji to seek his aid. If not, then how did Renji end up there?

Comment: are you talking about when the group of Soul reapers were sent to guard the Human world for a while and needed places to stay?

Comment: @Ryan the part I am talking about is, as I said, at the start of Season 4 when Renji stays with Kisuke and everyone is calling him Mr Moocher, when the other Mod Souls get introduced. I only vaguely recall that later Toshiro gets his his own place, Rongiku crashes at Orihime's and Ikaku crashes at one of Ichigo's friends who's sister crushes on Ikaku badly

Comment: Randomly Sumbling back here, I realized this question still has no answer. I suppose if i can Remember ill get to digging up some facts about a solid answer later. It all stopped mattering after season 2/ the Second arc, because he was proven innocent after Aizens Betrayal, so them knowing his location after that is expected. Gotta look into Rukia and Kiskues interactions in season 1. see if it was just by accident she found him or not.

Comment: Doesn't the fact that Rukia was able to find and get help of Urahara in the beginning itself prove that the Soul Society has an idea that a former Soul Reaper has set up shop? Many people such as Rukia, Renji (i.e. the new generation) may not know the true identity of Urahara, but I am sure Gotei 13 knows where he is. In fact, Ichigo's father also knows Urahara is in town after he regains his Reaper powers

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer?  Yes.  However, the arc you are speaking of does not exist in canon.  It was a filler arc.

Now, to expand upon the actual answer to your question.  The Gotei 13 does know where he is, in-fact, they even know where his shop is.  The reason they don't arrest or execute him is because he is still a useful asset to them.  Now, if he was useless or ended up causing too much trouble, they would likely dispose of him, especially after he helped Ichigo and the others to gain entrance into the Seretei (sorry if I misspelled that).